# AngularJS: Is this code with $eval optimal?

Tags: angularjs, eval

I've read a lot of bad stuff for using eval, should I use it in this case? Or is there a better solution? This code works fine btw.

```
$scope.check_button = function(value, target) {
    if($scope.$eval(target) == value) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: $eval isn't JS eval but it provides the similar function. It isn't 'optimal' by definition. What's the context for this code?

Comment: The question shouldn't be whether or not it's optimal. You either need it or you don't. Q: Are you using $eval on an angular expression? If so, you need it. If not, you don't.
What is `target`?